# MathJax: Hiding Mathjax loading process

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, loading, mathjax

I have `Mathjax` in my code that I show in `UIWebView`. 
while `Mathjax` is loading it shows the loading process n the left down corner of my `UIWebView` same as below pics, that i want to hide them. I do not want my user see them.

[image: loading process]

[image: loading process]

**note**: dummy solution is showing a fake "Loading" for some second that loading process finish and then show `UIWebView`. I really do not want to use this way.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your MathJax configuration, you can add this:

```
messageStyle: "none"
```

According to the documentation, this should do the trick: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html

Comment: Stack is telling I should wait 24 hour then I will be able to give your Bounty. you will got it man .

Answer (score 9):

Try this, it is working for me:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({messageStyle: 'none',tex2jax: {preview: 'none'}});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for `"preview": "none"` – it solved the other issue I had!

Comment: Thank you mariosm !

Answer (score 1):

Also add `showProcessingMessages: false`.