# Android WebView: how to load page after javascript execution

Tags: javascript, android, webview, get, android-asynctask

Relating to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915354/how-to-hide-android-webview-notifications),

I want to remove the notifications as well as the flicker that occurs when displaying TeX in a WebView in android.

I tried the AsyncTask method, to preload the page and then "download" it, before loading the data into the WebView but I'm stuck on an IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. This error is coming from the following code:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String r = "";
        try {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URLEncoder.encode(url[0], "UTF-8"));
            // get.setHeader("host", "http://myapp");
            HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(get);
        ...
    }
```

The line commented out is what I had tried to fix this error, but never worked.

Now I'm thinking I can't get around this because the `url[0]` that I'm loading is in the form: `javascript:somescript(input)` executed from a JS file stored in my assets, and maybe HttpGet requires a web server?

How can I hide the notifications and finish the JavaScript before updating the WebView then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpGet` class is for an HTTP request, so the URL must start with `http://`.

If you are using MathJax as the TeX viewer, then refering to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372615/mathjax-hiding-mathjax-loading-proccess), you could add `messageStyle: "none"` to your MathJax configuration. This way can disable MathJax's loading notifications in any environments.

Comment: Thanks David, but I've actually already disabled the messages with `messageStyle:"none"` and `showProcessingMessages: false` and I still have the other problem of eliminating the flicker while MathJax does it's "typesetting"

Comment: Maybe if I customised the MathJax.js file I could change the behaviour of MathJax to hide the DOM element while it typesets and then show after it completes?

Comment: Hi @Ozzy have you got solution for this flickering problem while loading mathjax? please let me know