# Typeset/render dynamic content with MathJax

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I used MathJax for displaying mathematics equations.It is working fine in statically written mathematics. But not working for dynamically added mathematics.

Here is my code

```
<body>
    //Static  
        <div>
            <span>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>                 
        </div> 
       //Dynamic 
        <div id="dynamic-pan">

        </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#dynamic-pan').empty();
                $('#dynamic-pan').append('<span>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>');
            });
        </script>
</body>
```

I have written mathematics in two span element. First one is statically declared and second one is dynamically added in document ready function

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

### MathJax v3

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html

- Sync typeset: `MathJax.typeset()`
- Async typeset: `MathJax.typesetPromise()`

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  const content = document.createElement('span')
  content.textContent = '\\(x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}\\)'

  const done = document.createElement('span')
  done.textContent = '   done!'
  
  const syncTypeset = document.querySelector('#syncTypeset')
  syncTypeset.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true))
  setTimeout(function () {
    MathJax.typeset()
    syncTypeset.appendChild(done.cloneNode(true))
  }, 3000)

  const asyncTypeset = document.querySelector('#asyncTypeset')
  asyncTypeset.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true))
  setTimeout(async function () {
    await MathJax.typesetPromise()
    asyncTypeset.appendChild(done.cloneNode(true))
  }, 3000)
}, 0)
```

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  },
  svg: {
    fontCache: 'global'
  }
};
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js" id="MathJax-script"></script>

//Static
<div>
  <span>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span> 
</div>
//Dynamic
<div id="syncTypeset">Sync after 3 second: </div>
<div id="asyncTypeset">Async after 3 seconds: </div>
```

### MathJax v2

You need to tell MathJax to look for unprocessed math which is done with the `Typeset()` method, since MathJax may be operating at the time of the call to `Typeset()` you need to add it to its queue

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $el = $('#dynamic-pan')
  $el.empty()
  $el.append('<span>\\(x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}\\)</span>')
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, $el[0]]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>

//Static
<div>
  <span>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span> 
</div>
//Dynamic
<div id="dynamic-pan"></div>
```

Refer to [this document](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/typeset.html) for more information

Edit: the character `\` has a special meaning on strings (it escapes the following char) to avoid this behavior make sure you use `\\` for it to appear in the final string

Comment: it's working, some characters of your string are being escaped, I've updated my answer with the result

Comment: When I run the code I can, for at few milliseconds, see the raw text of the equations and some boxes on the screen. One of them says Processing math: xx% I assume that MathJax runs over the page content to check if there is any math that needs formatting. Is there a way to avoid this? Is it possible to do the formatting before loading the page content.

Comment: add this line to your config: `showProcessingMessages: false`, note that this works for  V2

Comment: Thanks it works. I also got some inspiration from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372615/mathjax-hiding-mathjax-loading-process