# MathJax and KaTeX working in HTML but not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax, katex

When I write the following code in HTML it works fine:

```
<div id="output">
$$ \int f(x) dx $$
</div>
```

But when I try the following code in Javascript it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "$$ \int f(x)dx $$"
```

Why is this? The same problem happens whether i'm using Katex or MathJax

Comment: Pasha : ) do you have a minimal working example? Maybe you can add a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vjbez53/) or something where we can check.

Comment: you are certainly trying to trigger your javascript function once mathjax has already processed your page. You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224691/typeset-render-dynamic-content-with-mathjax and have explanation here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html

Comment: scraaappy - there is so much code in that solution i can't make sense of it. i understand i need to use MathJax.typeset() method but i don't have any idea how to actually implement it.

Comment: gengns - it works on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txzy7pcL/

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out...

You just have to put MathJax.typeset() on the line after your math in Javascript. Really simply.

Comment: You also need to double the backslashes in the string literal:  `'$$ \\int f(x)\\,dx $$'`